# ng-blur with uib-typeahead (ui-bootstrap)

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Skill1">Skill</label>
       <input type="text"
        ng-model="vm.skill1" 
        name="skill1"
        uib-typeahead="skill for skill in vm.skills | filter:$viewValue"
        class="form-control typeahead"
        ng-blur="vm.checkSkills(vm.skill1)"
        placeholder="" 
        required> 
   </div>
```

My environment is AngularJs, I'm trying to use ng-blur only when the user leave this field, however due to the typeahead, if I use the mouse to choose an option the typeahead suggest, the ng-blur "think" I left the field and activate the ng-blur just with the first letter I emtered
How can I override this?

Comment: Forgot the 2 lines :  <label for="Skill1">Skill</label>
                                         <input type="text

Comment: Please edit your post with these lines, so we can see them in context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ng-blur`,  required functionality can be achieved using

`typeahead-on-select="checkSkills($item,$model,$label)"`

**HTML**

```
<input  type="text"  ng-model="skill1" uib-typeahead="skill for skill in skills | filter:$viewValue" class="form-control typeahead" typeahead-on-select="checkSkills($item,$model,$label)"
```

**JS**

```
$scope.checkSkills = function(item, model, label){ 
   if(model){
      //your validation logic goes here
     // console.log (" Check skill, correctly set ", (item), model , label);
   }

 }
```

Plunker example : https://plnkr.co/edit/7N8TU2?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Anil. Your answer fix the issue with choosing a value from the type-ahead values. However, in case I key a value which is not found by the type-ahead I do not trigger the function, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add some slight delay inside your blur handler, so that it triggers after the onClick handler of uib-typeahead.

You can, for example, use $timeout() with a promise inside your vm.checkSkills method, eg:

```
$scope.checkSkills = function(skill) {
    $timeout(function() {}, 100).then(function() {
        // your logic
    });
}
```